# Change to blinking pin in javascript map?

Tags: javascript, html, json, amcharts

My javascript map is reading from a `json` stream that looks like this:

```
[{"title":"Site1","latitude":18.3764,"longitude":-67.1819},    
{"title":"Site2","latitude":18.2001,"longitude":-65.8081},
{"title":"Site3","latitude":18.3878,"longitude":-66.0998}]
```

The points are being drawn correctly, so that's great.

To this `json` I'll be adding an `inService` field. The `inService` field will be any of the following options: `[Monday, Tuesday, Sunday, Thursday]` and the `json` will look like this:

```
[{"title":"Site1","latitude":18.3764,"longitude":-67.1819,"inService":"Monday"},    
 {"title":"Site2","latitude":18.2001,"longitude":-65.8081,"inService":"Tuesday"},
 {"title":"Site3","latitude":18.3878,"longitude":-66.0998,"inService":"Sunday"},
 {"title":"Site4","latitude":18.1246,"longitude":-66.2607,"inService":"Thursday"}]
```

At the amcharts website, I saw these two new icons: [One that blinks](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/custom-html-elements-map-markers/) and another that's [a dot with a circle around it](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animations-along-lines/).

So my question is: Using the `json` above, how can I assign a blinking pin to the different types of values in `inService`?

For example:

- `Monday`: blinking blue pin
- `Tuesday`: blinking black pin
- `Sunday`: white dot with a circle around it (no blink)
- `Thursday` red dot with a circle around it (no blink)

And finally, we will be adding other types of status. How can I change the shapes? For example, the pins at the top will be squared instead of round?

Thanks for any help.

I tried using SO code preview, but it's not rendering the map. So I've also included it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wn61bfqb/):

```js
 AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "theme": "light",
  "imagesSettings": {
    "rollOverColor": "#089282",
    "rollOverScale": 1,
    "selectedScale": 0.5,
    "selectedColor": "#089282",
    "color": "#13564e",
    "selectable": false,
    "bringForwardOnHover": false
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "color": "#D3D3D3",
 "autoZoom": true
  },  
  "data": {
    "map": "puertoRicoHigh",
    "getAreasFromMap": true
  },
  "dataLoader": {
    "url": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/716619/30189.json",
    "format": "json",
    "showErrors": true,
    "postProcess": function(data, config, map) {
      // create a new dataProvider
      var mapData = map.data;
      
      // init images array
      if (mapData.images === undefined)
        mapData.images = [];
      
      // create images out of loaded data
      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var image = data[i];
        image.type = "circle";
        mapData.images.push(image);
      }
      return mapData;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#mapdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/puertoRicoHigh.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.js"></script>
<div id="mapdiv"></div>
```

Comment: You could add different css class based on the types of value. Then you can change color and make it blink via css.

Comment: Do you think  you can add an example?